# Strip string from $_product->get_title() to get a cleaner mini-cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using a customized `mini-cart.php` file, in which there is this line of code:

```
$product_name = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), 
    $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

I sell two types of products, "shorts" and "longshorts". I don't want to see these two words in my cart widget, because titles get too long and it's useless, so I want the results of `$product_name` to strip apart these words from the result.

To resume, actually I have this:

```
 - Short grey front pouch military
 - Short blue fisherman
 - Longshorts denim gray
 - Longshorts denim black
```

And I would prefer:

```
 - grey front pouch military
 - blue fisherman
 - denim gray
 - denim black
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a function in your theme's `functions.php` file that will find and remove those two words "shorts" and "longshorts" from a php string. Then you can add that function as a filter to the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` event that is being applied in your `mini-cart.php` Try something like:

```
function wpse_remove_shorts_from_cart_title( $product_name ) {
    $product_name = str_ireplace( 'longshorts', '', $product_name ); // remove "longshorts";
    $product_name = str_ireplace( 'shorts', '', $product_name ); // remove "shorts"

    return $product_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'wpse_remove_shorts_from_cart_title' );
```

Note, I've used `str_ireplace()` to cover occurrences whether they're capitalized or not (which is common in titles).

Comment: Will `longshorts` still get removed, or will you have to look for `long` since `shorts` is removed from the `product_name` in the first `str_ireplace`

Comment: @czerspalace Good catch. Thanks. I've switched the order of the searches. The first should only replace the whole string "longshorts" leaving "shorts" for the second string replace to pull out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but despite setting up the code correctly in my functions.php file (and fixing the missing brackets) it did not work and broke the cart and the "add to cart" somehow. I tried several variations in your code, but finally i found an easier solution, but not better since it has to do with tempering with a template file, which, i agree is never the best option when you can just add a filter. But it works...

Answer (score 0):

What i finally did was i took this line from mini-cart.php

```
<?php echo str_ireplace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
```

and changed it to

```
<?php echo str_ireplace( array( 'longshorts', 'short' ), '', $product_name ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
```

I had already disabled thumbnails anyway.
And it works!